Dante Server Config multi sock in side (route)
i have this config on dante
logoutput: syslog
user.privileged: root
user.unprivileged: nobody
clientmethod: none
socksmethod: username
internal: eth0 port = 5656
external: eth0
internal: eth0:0 port = 5656
internal: eth0:1 port = 5656
internal: eth0:2 port = 5656
external:  eth0:0
external:  eth0:1
external:  eth0:2
external.rotation: same-same
client pass {
from: 20.x.x.190/32 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error # connect disconnect
}
client pass {
from: 20.x.x.56/32 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error # connect disconnect
}
client pass {
from: 20.x.x.190/32 to: 0.0.0.0/0
log: error # connect disconnect
}
socks pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
command: bind connect udpassociate
log: error # connect disconnect iooperation
}
socks pass {
from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
command: bindreply udpreply
log: error # connect disconnect iooperation
}
when i connect into my dante socks server .. the socks not rotating.
Anybody can help me with this code?
i can donate
contact me at:
skype:truongngocvanphong
